# How to get the index of the clicked ItemizedIconOverlay in OSM

Tags: java, android, overlay, osmdroid, itemizedoverlay

How do i get the index position of the `ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay` when the user taps the icon? For example, when a user taps/clicks the first icon it should get the integer 0

```
List<GeoPoint> nodes = nodeCoordinates();
ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
Drawable newMarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_node);

for(int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
    anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem("Road", "Nodes", nodes.get(i)));
    anotherOverlayItemArray.get(i).setMarker(newMarker);
}

ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay
            = new ItemizedIconOverlay<>(
            this, anotherOverlayItemArray, null);
map.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example here
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/data/SampleMilitaryIconsItemizedIcons.java

ack, formatting issues....

`

itemOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<>(new ArrayList(),
                       new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                                 Toast.makeText(
                                         context,
                                         "Item '" + item.getTitle() + "' (index=" + index
                                                 + ") got single tapped up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 return true;
                            }

```
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                             Toast.makeText(
                                     context,
                                     "Item '" + item.getTitle() + "' (index=" + index
                                             + ") got long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             return false;
                        }
                   }, context);
```

`